# Nested associates the rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm trying to gain a better understanding of how to be leverage the Rails framework for my associations.

While it's not specific for my app, the structure is similar -- for my example, I'll use the standard blog associates.

Example Models:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts, :through => :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

My challenge is that I want to select all comments that belong to a specific author. I understand how to reference post and author elements that are associated with a specific post:

```
comment_author = Comment.first
puts comment_author.post.author.name
```

But as I stated I'm trying to select all comments that belong to a specific author. I could accomplish this by doing a find_by_sql, but I want to ensure db independence and I want to do this the "Rails way."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `has_many :through` assocication:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    has_many :comments, :through => :posts
end
```

Comment: So once I have established the has_many :through association, and I know the specific comment -- how can I best find all of the other comments by the same author? For example: comment = Comment.first. Now I want to find the rest of the comments by the author that authored the first comment...? ~Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

---

@Femaref provided the exact answer to your question and you should accept it. Mine is merely a complement.

---

If an author can leave comments on posts, here is what you might want to do:

```
class Author
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :responses, through: :posts, source: :comments                           
end

class Post
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :post
end
```

To get all the comments left by `sophia`: `sophia.comments`

To get all the comments left on `sophia`'s posts: `sophia.responses`

See the [options for `has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options) (especially `through` and `source`)

Comment: So this is perfect -- but allow me to complicate things a little. Lets say that I know a specific comment (comment.id) and I want to list all of the other comments by that user. So I will have to query who the author was and show all of the other comments by that author. I can use comment.post.author to find the author. THEN I could use the authorname.comments as you mentioned. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this in a single shot. Basically to walk up the chain and back down.

Comment: `comment.author.comments` returns all the comments left by the author of `comment`. Is that what you were looking for?